# How do you prepare deflate streams for PIGZ (parallel gzip)?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gzip

I am using the PIGZ library. https://zlib.net/pigz/

I compressed large files using multiple threads per file with this library and now I want to decompress those files using multiple threads per file too. As per the documentation:

> Decompression can’t be parallelized, at least not without specially
>   prepared deflate streams for that purpose.

However, the documentation doesn't specify how to do that, and I'm finding it difficult to find information on this.

How would I create these "specically prepared deflate streams" that PIGZ can utilise for decompression?

Comment: That doesn't state that PIGZ can do it, only that the streams need to be an unusual format for it to even be possible. The short of it is you'd need indexed places with reset or retransmitted compression dictionaries. bzip2 compresses in blocks, so pbzip2 can decompress in parallel.

Comment: If you want tools that can break large binaries into individually-compressed chunks and retrieve and decompress them in parallel, might I suggest [desync](https://github.com/folbricht/desync)? (It's a 3rd-party implementation of [casync](https://github.com/systemd/casync), which is designed to permit such capabilities but doesn't actually parallelize at present).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pigz does not currently support parallel decompression, so it wouldn't help to specially prepare such a deflate stream.

The main reason this has not been implemented is that, in most situations, decompression is fast enough to be i/o bound, not processor bound. This is not the case for compression, which can be much slower than decompression, and where parallel compression can speed things up quite a bit.

You could write your own parallel decompressor using zlib and pthread. pigz 2.3.4 and later will in fact make a specially prepared stream for parallel decompression by using the --independent (-i) option. That makes the blocks independently decompressible, and puts two sync markers in front of each to make it possible to find them quickly by scanning the compressed data.The uncompressed size of a block is set with --blocksize or -b. You might want to make that size larger than the default, e.g. 1M instead of 128K, to reduce the compression impact of using -i. Some testing will tell you how much your compression is reduced by using -i.

(By the way, pigz is not a library, it is a command-line utility.)

Comment: So if i understood you correctly, you're saying that pigz has the ability to produce deflate streams using the -i option, but I would have to actually write my own decompressor which could make use of these streams?

Comment: Seeing as you're the author, and while I've got you here ;) how is compression speed affected by blocksize?

Comment: Compression speed does not noticeably depend on blocksize. Unless you make the blocksize close to the file size, such that there aren't enough blocks to give to all of the cores to compress.

Comment: pigz always makes deflate streams. -i makes them independently decompressible and locatable. Then, yes, you would have to write your own decompressor to take advantage of that and do it in multiple cores.

Comment: @MarkAdler, I want to write parallel decompressor. But I can't find information about "two sync markers in front of each blocks". What does it look like and when is it put?

Comment: `00 00 ff ff 00 00 00 ff ff`. The `-b` option of pigz specifies the block size, where that many uncompressed bytes are in each block (default 128K). If `-i` is used, that marker is inserted between every such block.